# How can I kill a function after a timeout in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function, let's call it foo().

```
void foo()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        count ++;
        if(count>= 30000)
        {
          count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

foo() will run indefinitely, but let's say I want to fun my function foo() after 1 minute.
How can I do that using Qt?

I have already seen some people talking about one shot Qtime, but all the examples I have seen are about running my function after the timeout, but never killing it.

Comment: Killing a thread is not a safe operation. Instead you want to signal it to end.

Comment: foo is not a legal C++ function, and certainly not one that can run indefinitely. Regardless, you cannot kill a function. This is just not possible  C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @ Ted Lyngmo
Thanks a lot! Your answer was enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't *kill* threads but instead give them a condition to check if they should continue or quit. One way could use an `atomic<bool>` so that you can set it from another thread. You could also limit the time by measuring how long time the function has executed.

Example:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

void foo(std::atomic<bool>& run) {
    auto end_at = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::minutes(1);
    
    while(run == true && std::chrono::steady_clock::now() < end_at) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Setting `run` to `false` from another thread would signal `foo()` to quit and if it runs for longer than a minute it'll also quit.